# Recurring Milestone Every 2 Business Days

Tags: servicecloud, casemilestone, entitlements

Junior Admin here that is new to Entitlements and Milestones.

My requirements are that after the initial contact with the customer is made (First Milestone), the customer should be contacted very 2 business days.

I have created the second Milestone as follows:

**Milestone Name:** Follow-up Time
**Recurrence Type:** Sequential
**Time Trigger:** 1320 mins (I am basing this off an 11 hour day using our business hours 8am - 7pm x 60 mins x 2 = 1320)
**Start Time:** Milestone Criteria - Based on Record Type and Case Status.

The Milestone calculates the time correctly when it is first invoked.  Once it is marked as completed, it doesn't start the time back from the current time, it appears to be adding additional time.

Is this something that I am configuring incorrectly, or does this require an Apex Trigger?

Thanks in advance.